# ExtJS4: Value read in Store does not get populated in datafield

Tags: extjs, extjs4

As part of my EXTJS 4 learning process, I am trying to establish a simple process of database connection - loading a value in a data Store - taking the value and placing it in a dataField.

The data is loaded fine from the php script and placed into the Store via a json call. (as confirmed through FireBug)
However, the dataField, does not seem to be able to load the value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Model definition
Ext.define('FingerModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
                    {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
              ]
    }); 

//Store Definition
        var est_data = new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'FingerModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'finger.php',
                extraParams: {opt: 'getName'},
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results',
                    totalProperty: 'total'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true,
            // turn off remote sorting
            remoteSort: false
        });

//Form definition
var fingerForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            width: 500,
            title: 'Finger',
            waitMsgTarget: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Finger Form',
                items: [{
                        xtype:'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Location Name',
                        name: 'name'
                    }]
            }]
    });

        fingerForm.getForm().loadRecord(FingerModel);
```

Anybody see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.form.field.Text does not have a 'store' property. How would it know which row of the store to use?

You should use [Form.loadRecord()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) to load the model into the form, and it will set form fields with the same name as the model field names.

Comment: I updated the code above, using loadrecord() now, but I'm still not getting any love out of this thing.
I looked through the syntax pages of loadrecord, the form itself and the store and also some forums with similar issues already. No luck. :(

Comment: you need to load the store first, get a particular model from the store, and pass that instance to the form.loadRecord method. see store.load

Comment: Along with that, I also added the following line and it all works now. Thank you.

locationname.setValue(est_data.getById(1).data.name);